# GitLab Hosted Ruby Version Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab-ci

I'm testing out a simple Rails project with hosted GitLab.  My repository has Ruby version 2.3.0 and Rails version 5.0.1.  I created the basic gitlab-ci.yml file with the below code for CI.  When GitLab goes to run this file through the pipeline to add it I get the error:

activesupport-5.0.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.2, which is incompatible with
the current version, ruby 2.1.10p492

I'm not sure how to change the version of Ruby that GitLab is using.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
  - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec

rubocop:
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define the environment in which the code is run by using a Docker image.

Try adding

`image: ruby:2.3.0`

to the top of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

Comment: Perfect, I didn't realize it was that integrated with Docker.  Thanks for the quick response.  Will RSpec be utilized from my repository gemfile, or do I need to add that through gitlab-ci.yml as well?  Thanks again!

Comment: You should be fine because you're running bundle install as part of your before_script.
Every GitLab CI job is run in a new Docker container (assuming you're using Docker) so you should look in to using the caching function in it so that you don't have to download every gem on every job.